# Get a App version of the App Store using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, app-store

```
static func checkStoreVersion(completion: @escaping (String?) -> Void) {
    guard let info = Bundle.main.infoDictionary,
    let identifier = info["CFBundleIdentifier"] as? String else {
        return completion(nil)
    }
    
    guard let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/kr/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
        return completion(nil)
    }
    
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data,
              let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any],
              let results = json["results"] as? [[String: Any]],
              !results.isEmpty,
              let appStoreVersion = results[0]["version"] as? String else {
            print("checkStoreVersion : 0")
            
            return completion(nil)
        }
        print("checkStoreVersion : \(appStoreVersion)")
        return completion(appStoreVersion)
    }
    
    task.resume()
}
```

I used the code above to read the version of my registered app in the App Store and provide updates by comparison.

Since my app is my first registration, I'm done registering in the App Store, and I ran the app with Xcode to make sure I read the version correctly to test it, but this code didn't work.

resultCount is 0

Interestingly, if you search in a web browser with a URL that doesn't work in the app, the app information comes out well in the txt file.

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/kr/lookup?bundleId=\(identifier)") else {
    return completion(nil)
}
```

So I changed the address of url from http to https and it worked properly.

So I wondered if "Allow Arbitrary Loads" was the problem.

However, there was no problem when maintaining the status of http and looking up the bundle ID of other previously released apps by code.

I don't think 'Allow Arbitrary Loads' is a problem.
(Let me know if I'm wrong.)

```
guard let url = URL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/kr/lookup?id=\(id)") else {
    return completion(nil)
}
    
guard let url = URL(string: "http://itunes.apple.com/kr/lookup?id=\(id)") else {
    return completion(nil)
}
```

And I tested http and https with Apple ID method, not Bundle Id method. All worked well.

Why is the app information inquiry using http and bundle id not working on my just released app??

(I ran the same version through Xcode and tested it.)

Comment: Why would you use http?  Use https

Comment: @Paulw11 A lot of examples on the Internet were representing 'http'. I changed this to 'https', but I still wonder why.

Comment: For many years iOS has blocked http urls unless you specifically allow them via ATS config (allow arbitrary loads is the bulldozer solution, you can also enable http for specific domains)